# Refresh chart(javascript) after doing mysql Query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I've got a javascript for drawing a chart. I get my information out of my MySQL base. And I got 3 different buttons to get the different information out of the database.

My problem now is, I get the information out of my database, it shows it in the chart but when it shows the information it refreshes the page.

Is there a way to show the information after my page is refreshed? I actually tried to use the `window.onload` but that doesn't give me the wanted result.

in php I use the following code to get the info from my MySQL DB:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnProduct']))
{   
  ....
}
```

in html it's like this:

```
<div class="content">
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="submit" name="btnProduct" id="btnFilterProduct">
        </form>
</div>
```

And in JS I use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.onload = function()
    {   
        document.getElementById('btnFilterProduct').onclick = function()
        {
         ....
        }
    }
```

I know the PHP needs to refresh to get the data. and Javascript doesn't. But can I change the order? Or is there a way to change my JS to let it load AFTER the page is refreshed?

Answer (score 1):

To stop the page reload, modify your `onclick` function to be:

```
document.getElementById('btnFilterProduct').onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
}
```

[`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) stops the default behavior of the event, which in this case is to refresh the page since you have an empty `action`. Another option would be to not use a `form`. Just use the [`<button>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) element instead.

Comment: Yea that worked. Don't I need the `form` when I'm using `php`?

Comment: @Bart88 not at all. The form is only an HTML thing (unless you are using it for an action, which you aren't). Are you using jQuery to make the actual request to your PHP inside of the `onclick`?

Comment: No,I use the `onclick` just to do some calculations and set the information in my chart.

Comment: Ah, your posting the page to itself. Then yes, keep the form. A more ideal way would be to separate out the PHP code that gets the data into its own script which can be called with an AJAX call. That way your server only sends the new data again instead of the entire page.

Comment: I just noticed when I'm going to my page for the first time, it doesn't show anything. Since it needs a page refresh to get my data from my MysqlDB...

Comment: Have your PHP run the MySQL code before the initial page load

Comment: Well how Do I do that? I need to push my button first to get the right information

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101048/discussion-between-bart88-and-matthew-herbst).